# Empty Pack Variadic Template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Let's say I have some action to perform, at compile time:

```
enum class Action {A, B};
```

Now I write a template variadic function which performs a possible combination of action in sequence:

```
template <Action a>
void applyAction();

template <typename = void>
void applyActions() {}

template <Action a, Action... as>
void applyActions() {
  applyAction<a>();
  applyActions<as...>();
}
```

This code is fine. Indeed:

```
void foo() {
  applyActions<Action::A, Action::B>();
}
```

correctly generates:

```
call void applyAction<(Action)0>()
call void applyAction<(Action)1>()
```

[GodBolt Example Here](https://godbolt.org/g/ywU3i4)

---

In order to achieve the expansion pack termination, I had to declare the dummy function:

```
template <typename = void> void applyActions() {}
```

which is quite "ugly" to me because it gives the possibility to invoke a generic type.

**In C++11**, Is there a way to declare a variadic function which accepts an empty parameter pack?

*Of course,* its declaration does not have to bring to call ambiguity with the needed function:

```
template <Action a, Action... as>
void applyActions();
```

Something like:

```
template <Action.. = {}>
void applyActions() {}
```

---

[Here](https://godbolt.org/g/dAomJN) a not compilable example because of a call ambiguity. But it gives an idea of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative way to structure it so you can remove the 'ugly' default is the following, which also removes the recursion and would work with an empty actions parameter pack,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum class Action {A, B};

template <Action a>
void applyAction()
{
   std::cout << "Action  " << (int)a << std::endl;
}

template <Action... as>
void applyActions() {
    using do_= int[];
    (void)do_{0, ( 
       applyAction<as>()
    ,0)...}; 
}

void foo() {
  applyActions<Action::A, Action::B>();
}

void bar() {
  applyActions<Action::B, Action::A>();
}


int main() {
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/be8kRO)

As pointed out by HolyBlackCat, in c++17 you could just use a fold expression,

```
template <Action... as>
void applyActions() {

       (applyAction<as>(), ...);
}
```

Comment: Cool! Can you explain a little bit the syntax `{0, (applyAction<as>(),0)...,0}`?
I got this is an array initialization, but can you extend a little bit, please?

Comment: Yes, the first zero is such that if the parameter pack is zero sized, you will not be initializing a zero sized array. Its redundant in this case, with 'as...' never empty. The second zero is redundant (i've edited). the (applyAction<as>(),0) just uses the fact that the comma operator results in the value of the right operand. The point being that it must be an int.

Answer (score 1):

> In C++11, Is there a way to declare a variadic function which accepts an empty parameter pack?

Yes: there is and it's trivial

```
template <Action...>
void applyActions()
```

The problem is that, in your case, collide with the function that accept with one or more elements

```
template <Action a, Action... as>
void applyActions()
```

and when you call `applyActions<as...>();` with a not empty `as...` pack, both template match.

The use of a template function with the same name but a different genre of argument (and a default value)

```
template <typename = void>
void applyActions() {}
```

it's (IMHO) an extremely smart, cheap and elegant way to solve the termination problem.